# Wamp server has deleted my Service Package

Tags: wampserver, flash-builder, flashcatalyst

I just when to continue with my web site in Flash builder and there was an error. When I looked into it my Service folder which held my PHP script is missing and unfortunately I hadn't backed up for some months.

Has anyone had this issue and is there a way to get it back? it just disappeared :(
C:\wamp\www\index-debug\services\CustomerService.php is missing

Answer (score 0):

Never happened to me. You can use "Handy Recovery" or "recuva" to get your file back. Good luck with that